# MySQL Count With Statement

Tags: mysql, count

can anyone help me on how should i count the `jq.batchid != 0 and tl.taskqueueid IS NOT NULL`

Here is the initial data:

```
+---------------+-----------+---------+---------------+
|  taskqueueid  |  batchid  |  jobid  |  taskqueueid  |
+---------------+-----------+---------+---------------+
|      19       |     0     |   140   |     (NULL)    |
+---------------+-----------+---------+---------------+
|      21       |    103    |   140   |       21      |
+---------------+-----------+---------+---------------+
|      22       |    104    |   140   |       22      |
+---------------+-----------+---------+---------------+
|      23       |    105    |   140   |     (NULL)    |
+---------------+-----------+---------+---------------+
|      20       |     0     |   140   |     (NULL)    |
+---------------+-----------+---------+---------------+
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(jq.batchid),COUNT(tl.taskqueueid)
  FROM jobqueue jq
  LEFT JOIN taskslogs tl
    ON jq.taskqueueid=tl.taskqueueid
   AND jq.documentgroupid=0
   AND jq.batchid!=0
   AND tl.statusDefinitionID=1
 WHERE jq.jobid=140;
```

The above query result is:

```
+--------------------+-----------------------+
| COUNT(jq.batchid)  | COUNT(tl.taskqueueid) |
+--------------------+-----------------------+
|         5          |           2           |
+--------------------+-----------------------+
```

And I want a result of:

```
+--------------------+-----------------------+
| COUNT(jq.batchid)  | COUNT(tl.taskqueueid) |
+--------------------+-----------------------+
|         3          |           2           |
+--------------------+-----------------------+
```

Can anyone help me on how should I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a very nice trick for these kind of count:

```
SELECT
    SUM(jq.batchid > 0) as nb_batchid_positive,
    SUM(tl.taskqueueid IS NOT NULL) as nb_taskqueueid_not_null
FROM jobqueue jq
LEFT JOIN taskslogs tl
    ON jq.taskqueueid=tl.taskqueueid
    AND jq.documentgroupid=0
    AND tl.statusDefinitionID=1
WHERE jq.jobid=140;
```

SUM(BOOLEAN CONDITION) gives you exactly the number of rows matching the condition.

Comment: You mean: *"`COUNT(*)` gives you the total number of rows."* I haven't heard of a "non-null row" before.

Comment: Assuming a nullable column "my_col", "SELECT COUNT(my_col) FROM my_table;" will give you the total number of non-null rows.

Comment: That is correct. But `COUNT(*)` is different than `COUNT(column)`

Comment: My apologies then, my answer was indeed written a bit too fast and COUNT(*) stands for COUNT(jq.batchid) and COUNT(tl.taskqueueid) :/

Comment: No, your answer is correct (that's why I upvoted it :) Just the wording in that line needs polishing I think.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a left join, count will always return the same number of rows for both elements, as they can only ever be the same number of rows.

You would need to do two counts, one one each table for the condtion you are looking into.